# Register and unregister OCX dll

Tags: c#, .net, ocx

Why Register a DLL?
I have a lot of basic doubts on DLLs and i have tried to put them in a listed Questions form as below:

1. Why do we need to register a DLL?
2. What happens when we register a DLL?
3. When i use a "LoadLibrary" in my C# code, i do not do any registration.
   Whats the connection/difference between the two?
   (Registering a DLL and Loading a DLL)
4. Can i register all the DLLs? or are there some DLLs which cannot be registered and why?

If anyone can recommend some online articles for clarifying my doubts it would be big help!
otherwise snippet code.

im using this code but it doesnt give exactly what i need, thats why i asked here....
its working fine in 32-bit machine but it gives denied path error in 64 bit machine

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Management;
using System.IO;
using CCC_DLLRegistar.LoadLibrary;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Diagnostics;



namespace CCC_DLLRegistar
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        #region Is64BitOperatingSystem (IsWow64Process)


        public static bool Is64BitOperatingSystem()
        {
            if (IntPtr.Size == 8)  // 64-bit programs run only on Win64
            {
                return true;
            }
            else  // 32-bit programs run on both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows
            {
                // Detect whether the current process is a 32-bit process 
                // running on a 64-bit system.
                bool flag;
                return ((DoesWin32MethodExist("kernel32.dll", "IsWow64Process") &&
                    IsWow64Process(GetCurrentProcess(), out flag)) && flag);
            }
        }


        static bool DoesWin32MethodExist(string moduleName, string methodName)
        {
            IntPtr moduleHandle = GetModuleHandle(moduleName);
            if (moduleHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return (GetProcAddress(moduleHandle, methodName) != IntPtr.Zero);
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string moduleName);

        [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string procName);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool IsWow64Process(IntPtr hProcess, out bool wow64Process);

        #endregion


        #region Is64BitOperatingSystem (WMI)


        public static bool Is64BitOperatingSystem(string machineName,
            string domain, string userName, string password)
        {
            ConnectionOptions options = null;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
            {

                options = new ConnectionOptions();
                options.Username = userName;
                options.Password = password;
                options.Authority = "NTLMDOMAIN:" + domain;
            }
            // Else the connection will use the currently logged-on user

            // Make a connection to the target computer.
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" +
                (string.IsNullOrEmpty(machineName) ? "." : machineName) +
                "\\root\\cimv2", options);
            scope.Connect();


            ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery(
                "SELECT AddressWidth FROM Win32_Processor");

            // Perform the query and get the result.
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
            ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();
            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in queryCollection)
            {
                if (queryObj["AddressWidth"].ToString() == "64")
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        #endregion




        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private string _RootPath = string.Empty;
        private string _path = string.Empty;
        private List<string> _Regfiles;

        DLLHelper obj;

        public string path
        {
            get { return _path; }
            set { _path = value; }
        }


        public string RootPath
        {
            get { return _RootPath; }
            set { _RootPath = value; }

         }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // Solution 1. Is64BitOperatingSystem (IsWow64Process)
            // Determine whether the current operating system is a 64 bit 
            // operating system.
            bool f64bitOS = Is64BitOperatingSystem();
            //Console.WriteLine("The current operating system {0} 64-bit.",
            //    f64bitOS ? "is" : "is not");

            // Solution 2. Is64BitOperatingSystem (WMI)
            // Determine whether the current operating system is a 64 bit 
            // operating system through WMI. The function is also able to 
            // query the bitness of OS on a remote machine.
            try
            {
                f64bitOS = Is64BitOperatingSystem(".", null, null, null);
                //Console.WriteLine("The current operating system {0} 64-bit.",
                //    f64bitOS ? "is" : "is not");
                if (f64bitOS == true)
                {
                    RootPath = "C:\\windows\\SysWow64\\";
                }
                else
                {
                    RootPath = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\";
                }

                bool isAdmin = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
                 .IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator) ? true : false;

                if (isAdmin)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("you are an administrator");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You are not an administrator");
                }
                path = Application.StartupPath + "\\CCC DLL\\";

                List<string> regsvr = new List<string>();

                foreach (string s in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*").Select(Path.GetFileName))
                {
                    regsvr.Add(Application.StartupPath + "\\CCC DLL\\" + s);
                }

                foreach (string filepath in regsvr)
                {
                    Registar_Dlls(filepath);
                }

                _Regfiles=new List<string>();
                foreach (string s in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.dll").Select(Path.GetFileName))
                {
                    _Regfiles.Add(Application.StartupPath + "\\CCC DLL\\" + s);
                    if (DLLHelper.UnmanagedDllIs64Bit(Application.StartupPath + "\\CCC DLL\\" + s) == true)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("62 bit");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("32 bit");
                    }
                }

                foreach (string s in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.ocx").Select(Path.GetFileName))
                    _Regfiles.Add(Application.StartupPath + "\\CCC DLL\\" + s);



                    foreach (string filepath in _Regfiles)
                    {
                        obj = new DLLHelper(filepath);
                        obj.DumpToFile(RootPath + obj.GetDLLName());                       
                    }

                    MessageBox.Show("Register Colmpleted");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Is64BitOperatingSystem throws the exception: {0}",
                //    ex.Message);
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }




        public  void Registar_Dlls(string filePath)
        {

            try
            {
                //'/s' : Specifies regsvr32 to run silently and to not display any message boxes.
                //string arg_fileinfo = "/s" + " " + "\"" + filePath + "\"";

                string arg_fileinfo = RootPath +"\regsvr32.exe"+" "+ "/s" + " "  + "\"" + filePath;
                Process reg = new Process();
                //This file registers .dll files as command components in the registry.
                reg.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"; //"regsvr32.exe";
                reg.StartInfo.Arguments = arg_fileinfo;
                reg.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                reg.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                reg.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                if (System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6)
                {
                    reg.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
                }
                reg.Start();
                reg.WaitForExit();
                reg.Close();
               // MessageBox.Show("Successfully Registered your Ocx files");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is too broad for SO... If you are curious - read a book about COM/ActiveX - second 50-100 pages of most such books cover these questions. Otherwise - just follow instructions...

Comment: Registration is specific to COM servers.  What you are trying to do in this code is pointless, dangerous and very likely to just fail.